# Read from file, store into linked list then print to file again

Tags: c++, linked-list

I have a constructor and a destructor for a class called StringList. I created functions that add, remove and clear the strings within the linked list. I want this program to retain its added strings even when the program is ended. One way that i can do this is to have my constructor read from a file and my destructor save the strings to that same file. I am brand new into programming and ive been searching how to do this for a linked list but ive hit dead ends so far. The file i read from is called Read.txt, when the destructor is called, all the strings are saved to this file. 
The Read.txt file contains a list as such:

```
HELLO
MOM
BART
CART
PETS
```

Here is the code:

```
StringList::StringList()
{
    ifstream infile;
  // i know how to open the file i just dont really have a single clue on how to set each string into the linked list


}

StringList::~StringList()
{
    StringListNode *next;
    for (StringListNode *sp = pTop; sp != 0; sp = next)
    {
        next = sp->pNext;
        delete sp;
    }
}
```

Any suggestions or examples would be much appreciated. If you need further info or anymore code i wrote, please let me know asap

Comment: If you really want persistent storage, why not use [a database?](http://sqlite.org/)

Comment: Don't you just want to call your add() method for each string you find in the string storage file, e.g. Read.txt?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is my suggestion. Hope that can help you.

```
StringListNode *cur = pTop;  // I guess pTop is the head of your list
for each string s  // read
{
    cur = new StringListNode(s);  // call the constructor of StringListNode
    cur = cur->pNext;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code to accomplish what you want. For reading, you should have a while loop over the input file stream until no more strings can be read. Add each string using your already written add function. Then for destruction you should open a file stream and save each element of the list accordingly.

```
StringList::StringList() {
    ifstream ifs("MyFilename.txt");
    string s;
    while(ifs >> s)
        Add(s);
}

StringList::~StringList() {
    ofstream ofs("MyFilename.txt");
    StringListNode *next;
    for (StringListNode *sp = pTop; sp != 0; sp = next)
    {
        ofs << sp->element << endl;
        next = sp->pNext;
        delete sp;
    }
}
```

Comment: You are assuming there are no spaces in each element. Prefer `std::getline()` over `operator>>` in your while loop. flushing each line is very inefficient. Prefer `'\n'` over `std::endl`.